# android lsitview OpenGLRenderer and texture issue?

Tags: android, listview

my application calling posts from remote server , whoever when i open any activity has long text the listview style has gone like border radius etc , and i got repeated message on `Eclipse` console say

`08-06 00:29:37.841: W/OpenGLRenderer(7388): Shape round rect too large to be rendered into a texture (696x7190, max=4096x4096)`

i know the problem from the post how has long text inside listview , but is there any way to fix this ? i really tired to fix this issue !

Answer (score 4):

this is how to fix this issue , finally lol

After a fair amount of google research, turning off hardware acceleration was the only workaround found. Set the following in your manifest for the entire application

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>`

or for the activity

`<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />`

Comment: definitely worked also for me, but not a good solution, try find some better one, and'll post it here if i found something :) thx anyways

Answer (score 0):

for me the fix was just remove the "rounded corner" (radius parameter) from the rectangle, and it just did the trick, disabling hardware acceleration also did the trick, but I didn't want to do that.
all the best,